# Rotate Hierarchical Bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using hierarchical D3.JS Bar chart.

here is the link

[Click here to see the chart](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1283663)

I want to rotate this chart as vertical position.

The following is code is used to rotate the chart as vertical position

```
//svg Rotate
svg.attr("transform", function (d) { 
        return "rotate(-90)"
     });
```

But chart is going towards top of the browser.

[Click here to see the chart after that code has changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DMKQJ.jpg)

when i add the following code.

```
svg.attr("transform", function (d) { 
        return "rotate(-90deg)"
     });
```

The chart going inside to the browser the attachment

[see the chart after i add -90 deg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnoF3.jpg)

Can anyone tell me how to show the display as per my requirement.

Thanks

Vinoth,

Comment: Try this `rotate(-90deg)`.

Comment: : @abhishekkannojia : that is not rotate the D3. That came to normal position and slightly go inside to browser i have upload the photo in my question please refer the photo. when was i add the code rotate(-90deg).

Comment: Smells like an X-Y problem to me--instead of rotating, you might want to slightly refactor the original script so that what is mapped to the x-axis is mapped to the y-axis, and vice versa, It should be a rather trivial change. Using a 90deg rotation is kind of brute-forcing things, because all your axis labels will be rotated, and your coordinates rotated, too (which makes it very difficult to troubleshoot or maintain).

Comment: :@Terry: Did you try this Chart any of your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Terry said in his comment this is an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).  You are asking "how do I rotate the chart?"; when you should be asking "how do I redraw the chart to be vertical?".   Well, here it is all refactored:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

rect.background {
  fill: white;
}

.axis {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
}

</style>
<body>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var margin = {top: 10, right: 120, bottom: 120, left: 120},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var barHeight = 20;

var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(["steelblue", "#ccc"]);

var duration = 750,
    delay = 25;

var partition = d3.layout.partition()
    .value(function(d) { return d.size; });

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "background")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .on("click", up);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")")
    .append("line")
    .attr("x1", "100%");

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis");

d3.json("https://jsonblob.com/api/f577d19c-0f2b-11e7-a0ba-09040711ce47", function(error, root) {
  if (error) throw error;

  partition.nodes(root);
  y.domain([0, root.value]).nice();
  down(root, 0);
});

function down(d, i) {
  if (!d.children || this.__transition__) return;
  var end = duration + d.children.length * delay;

  // Mark any currently-displayed bars as exiting.
  var exit = svg.selectAll(".enter")
      .attr("class", "exit");

  // Entering nodes immediately obscure the clicked-on bar, so hide it.
  exit.selectAll("rect").filter(function(p) { return p === d; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Enter the new bars for the clicked-on data.
  // Per above, entering bars are immediately visible.
  var enter = bar(d)
      .attr("transform", stack(i))
      .style("opacity", 1);

  // Have the text fade-in, even though the bars are visible.
  // Color the bars as parents; they will fade to children if appropriate.
  enter.select("text").style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
  enter.select("rect").style("fill", color(true));

  // Update the x-scale domain.
  y.domain([0, d3.max(d.children, function(d) { return d.value; })]).nice();

  // Update the x-axis.
  svg.selectAll(".y.axis").transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .call(yAxis);

  // Transition entering bars to their new position.
  var enterTransition = enter.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .delay(function(d, i) { return i * delay; })
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + barHeight * i * 2.5 + "," + 0 + ")"; });

  // Transition entering text.
  enterTransition.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition entering rects to the new y-scale.
  enterTransition.select("rect")
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(!!d.children); });

  // Transition exiting bars to fade out.
  var exitTransition = exit.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .style("opacity", 1e-6)
      .remove();

  // Transition exiting bars to the new y-scale.
  exitTransition.selectAll("rect")
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); });

  // Rebind the current node to the background.
  svg.select(".background")
      .datum(d)
    .transition()
      .duration(end);

  d.index = i;
}

function up(d) {
  if (!d.parent || this.__transition__) return;
  var end = duration + d.children.length * delay;

  // Mark any currently-displayed bars as exiting.
  var exit = svg.selectAll(".enter")
      .attr("class", "exit");

  // Enter the new bars for the clicked-on data's parent.
  var enter = bar(d.parent)
      .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(" + barHeight * i * 2.5 + "," + 0 + ")"; })
      .style("opacity", 1e-6);

  // Color the bars as appropriate.
  // Exiting nodes will obscure the parent bar, so hide it.
  enter.select("rect")
      .style("fill", function(d) { return color(!!d.children); })
    .filter(function(p) { return p === d; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the y-scale domain.
  y.domain([0, d3.max(d.parent.children, function(d) { return d.value; })]).nice();

  // Update the y-axis.
  svg.selectAll(".y.axis").transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .call(yAxis);

  // Transition entering bars to fade in over the full duration.
  var enterTransition = enter.transition()
      .duration(end)
      .style("opacity", 1);

  // Transition entering rects to the new y-scale.
  // When the entering parent rect is done, make it visible!
  enterTransition.select("rect")
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .each("end", function(p) { if (p === d) d3.select(this).style("fill-opacity", null); });

  // Transition exiting bars to the parent's position.
  var exitTransition = exit.selectAll("g").transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .delay(function(d, i) { return i * delay; })
      .attr("transform", stack(d.index));

  // Transition exiting text to fade out.
  exitTransition.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition exiting rects to the new scale and fade to parent color.
  exitTransition.select("rect")
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
      .style("fill", color(true));

  // Remove exiting nodes when the last child has finished transitioning.
  exit.transition()
      .duration(end)
      .remove();

  // Rebind the current parent to the background.
  svg.select(".background")
      .datum(d.parent)
    .transition()
      .duration(end);
}

// Creates a set of bars for the given data node, at the specified index.
function bar(d) {
  var bar = svg.insert("g", ".x.axis")
      .attr("class", "enter")
      .attr("transform", "translate(15,0)")
    .selectAll("g")
      .data(d.children)
    .enter().append("g")
      .style("cursor", function(d) { return !d.children ? null : "pointer"; })
      .on("click", down);

  bar.append("text")
      .attr("x", barHeight / 2)
      .attr("y", height + 10)
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .style("text-anchor", "start")
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .attr("transform", "rotate(45 " + (barHeight / 2) + " " + (height + 10) + ")")

  bar.append("rect")
      .attr("width", barHeight)
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); });

  return bar;
}

// A stateful closure for stacking bars horizontally.
function stack(i) {
  var y0 = 0;
  return function(d) {
    var tx = "translate(" + barHeight * i * 1.5 + "," + y0 + ")";
    y0 += y(d.value);
    return tx;
  };
}

</script>
```

Comment: :@ Mark : Thank you for your help : This bar are only going towards but it not roleback to normal mode. can you check the snippet code output.

Comment: Hi, mark, I review your code. i get error from this line  " x.domain([0, d3.max(d.parent.children, function(d) { return d.value; })]).nice(); " when i run into chrome browser and i check it by inspect element.

Comment: @Vinoth, totally missed those transitions on in the `up` function.   See my edits above.

Comment: for responsive :browser width and height has been set to d3 width and height. i am using following code to responsive "window.onresize = function () { d3.select('svg>g').remove(); down(d,i); stack(i); bar(d); up(d); }" this code is not working if i resize the browser the chart has not visible. How to solve this.

Comment: Hi mark: I am trying to make responsive to this chart by using following code " "window.onresize = function () { d3.select('svg>g').remove(); down(d,i); stack(i); bar(d); up(d); }"  but it is not working. How to solve this plz help

Comment: @Vinoth, you are becoming [a help vampire](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258206/what-is-a-help-vampire).  Refrain from piling on additional questions in the comments.  New questions belong in a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).  Remember to upvote and accept the answers that help you.

Comment: Hi Mark, Don't Tease me I'm new to D3 that is the main reason to ask many question. Thank you for your help